# Why is my sunspot solr query not working? (Limit a 'fq' to only one part side of OR expression?)

Tags: solr, sunspot, sunspot-solr

I have several fields that can be searched without restriction, we'll call these fields `id1`, `id2`, and `id3`.

There is also another set of fields I'll call `name`, and `description` that I want to search *only* if a boolean field (`permit`) is true, like this:

```
(id1 || id2 || id3) || (permit && (name || description))
```

This is as close as I've gotten:

```
searchable do
  text :description
  text :name, :boost => 5

  text :id1,  :boost => 10
  text :id2,  :boost => 10
  text :id3,  :boost => 10

  boolean :permit, :using => :has_permit?
end

Sunspot.search(Item) do
  any do
    fulltext query, :fields => [:id1, :id2, :id3]
    all do
      with :permit, true
      fulltext query, :fields => [:name, :description]
    end
  end
  paginate :page => page, :per_page => per_page
end
```

But it falls short--it only returns records that have :permit => true, even if the search query exactly matches one of the `id*` columns.

Here's what I see in the rails log:

```
SOLR Request (10.3ms)  [ path=select parameters={fq: ["type:Item", "permit:true"], q: "(_query_:"{!edismax qf='id1 id2 id3'}MYQUERY" OR _query_:"{!edismax qf='name description'}MYQUERY")", fl: "* score", start: 0, rows: 30} ]
```

Clearly, the "permit:true" in the `fq` param is being applied to the whole query instead of just to the second clause.

What am I doing wrong and how do I get the results I'm after?